# How to get a mysql inner join data (one to many relation) from node js nested array of objects

Tags: node.js, express, mysql2

I am tried to get an array from mysql2 in node js but I am only getting two separate arrays from mysql2 How can I resolve the issue

```
export const getOrderProducts = async (req, res) => {
  const { user_id, order_id } = req.params;

  const opt = {
    sql: `select orders.id , orders.order_status ,products.id as product_id, products.name,products.quantity  from users INNER JOIN orders on orders.user_id=users.unique_id INNER JOIN delivery_details on delivery_details.order_id = orders.id INNER JOIN delivery_types on delivery_types.id=orders.delivery_type_id INNER JOIN order_products on order_products.order_id = orders.id INNER JOIN products on products.id = order_products.product_id where users.unique_id='${user_id}' and orders.id='${order_id}'`,
    nestTables: true,
  };

  try {
    const data = await query(opt);
    return res.json(Success("Orders", data));
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json(Error("Internal Server Error try again", error));
  }
};

Output :

 [
        {
            "orders": {
                "id": 12,
                "order_status": "PENDING"
            },
            "products": {
                "product_id": 4,
                "name": "Sugarcane Juice",
                "quantity": "1"
            }
        },
        {
            "orders": {
                "id": 12,
                "order_status": "PENDING"
            },
            "products": {
                "product_id": 5,
                "name": "Milo ice",
                "quantity": "1"
            }
        }
    ]

Expected Output : 

 [
        {            
            "id": 12,
            "order_status": "PENDING",
            "products": [{
                "product_id": 4,
                "name": "Sugarcane Juice",
                "quantity": "1"
            },{
                "product_id": 5,
                "name": "Milo ice",
                "quantity": "1"
            }]     
        }
 ]
```

I am using the mysql2 package and options sql and nestTables as you see below code how can I get the expected output of my code and i achieved only MySQL code without any JS functions Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please do not forget that mysql is a relational database, not a nosql one! It will always return rows and columns, not a hierarchical data. You have to format the output to match your requirements in node.js.

Comment: @Shadow how can archive expected output in node js and also it is only two tables joining data same thing I merge three or more tables how can I do hierarchical data in node js from mysql

Answer (score 0):

you can restructure returned data before sending it in the responce. For examlpe:

```
export const getOrderProducts = async (req, res) => {
  const { user_id, order_id } = req.params;

  const opt = {
    sql: `select orders.id , orders.order_status ,products.id as product_id, products.name,products.quantity  from users INNER JOIN orders on orders.user_id=users.unique_id INNER JOIN delivery_details on delivery_details.order_id = orders.id INNER JOIN delivery_types on delivery_types.id=orders.delivery_type_id INNER JOIN order_products on order_products.order_id = orders.id INNER JOIN products on products.id = order_products.product_id where users.unique_id='${user_id}' and orders.id='${order_id}'`,
    nestTables: true,
  };

  try {
    const data = await query(opt);
    const result = {
      id: data[0].orders.id,
      order_status: data[0].orders.order_status,
      products: data.map(row => ({
        product_id: row.products.product_id,
        name: row.products.name,
        quantity: row.products.quantity,
      })),
    };
    return res.json(Success("Orders", result));
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json(Error("Internal Server Error try again", error));
  }
};
```

Comment: Hey buddy, as your code snippet return successful give an single array of object but i need a multiple orders returns a multiple array of objects